# How to simplify import own files?

Tags: typescript

Let's we have the next structure

```
─project
    ├───content
    │       content.ts
    │
    └───modules
        └───api
            └───service
                    service.ts
```

Inside `content.ts` there is const value `OFFSET`

```js
const OFFSET = 10
```

Inside `service.ts` need to import `OFFSET`

```js
import { OFFSET } from '../../../content/content'
```

What I need to do in order to simplify import to

```js
import { OFFSET } from 'content'
```

Just like is happen with external library

```js
import { Modal, Heading } from 'flowbite-svelte'
```

Comment: I think you should have a look to the TS ["Module resolution"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Not what you exactly want, but maybe [TSConfig `paths`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths):

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
        "content/*": ["./content/*"]
    },
}
```

```
import { OFFSET } from 'content/content';
```