# Add path to search classes in intellisense

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm working on a TypeScript project in Visual Studio Code and I want Intellisense to search for classes and give me tips not only in my project folder but also in another folder.

This is my folder structure:

```
├───@lib
│   └───typescript
│       └───src
│           └───logger.ts
│
└───typescript
    └───myproject
            main.ts
            myproject.code-workspace
            package.json
            tsconfig.json
```

The project I'm working on is on `typescript/myproject` folder.

While editing `typescript/myproject/main.ts`, I want to import `Logger` class from `../../@lib/typescript/src/logger`.
This works fine if I manually type the path, but I want to type `Logg` in the editor and be able to use Intellisense to auto import `Logger` class from the desidered path, like if the class was in the same project or in any subfolder.

I already tried to create a workspace (`myproject.code-workspace`) with both folders (`myproject` and `typescript`, or `typescript/src`).

I also tried to edit `typescript/myproject/tsconfig.json` adding path to `"include"` like below, but nothing happens:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ....
    },
    "include": [
        "../../@lib/typescript",
        "../../@lib/typescript/src"
    ]
}
```

How to tell intellisense to search classes and methods from `../../@lib/typescript/src` path?

Comment: pretty sure what you want is [`paths`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths), for which there are already several Q&A on SO, and then you should find which one your question is a duplicate of and close it as a duplicate. Ex. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76897670/11107541), though i'm sure there's a better dup-target out there

Comment: @starball Thanks for your comment. I tried to put "lib/*": ["../../@lib/typescript/src/*"] in the `paths` object, but Intellisense still doesn't work as intended: I mean, if I start typing "Logg", Logger class is not automatically shown by Intellisense. I need to let Intellisense know which paths it should check to import classes. I'm not sure that tsconfig.compilerOptions.path is used for this.